# What are these "trash" files on my local drive?

Tags: windows, windows-10

This isn't the first time it has happened, but now that I clean installed the new Windows, I'd like to have everything neat and sparkling. Unfortunately, these files are in the way of achieving that.  I'm not sure what's causing them, but so far, the only major software I've installed are Steam and Photoshop. I think it's Photoshop's fault, but as I said, I'm not sure.

What I want to know is what these things are, and more importantly, if I can delete them.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These files are supposed to be temporary files that are placed in the root directory of the largest drive when installing Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable, which is commonly installed alongside many software packages.  They can be safely deleted.

[Here's the Microsoft article with a list of files.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/950683)

Per the article above, the following files should be safe to delete:

```
install.exe 
install.res.1028.dll 
install.res.1031.dll 
install.res.1033.dll 
install.res.1036.dll 
install.res.1040.dll 
install.res.1041.dll 
install.res.1042.dll 
install.res.2052.dll 
install.res.3082.dll 
vcredist.bmp 
globdata.ini 
install.ini 
eula.1028.txt 
eula.1031.txt 
eula.1033.txt 
eula.1036.txt 
eula.1040.txt 
eula.1041.txt 
eula.1042.txt 
eula.2052.txt 
eula.3082.txt 
VC_RED.MSI
VC_RED.cab
```